# Swift Special Unicode Characters in String Literals

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

Am trying to do the experiment the following in Swift, as its written in apple developer documentation:
`let encircledLetter: Character = "i\u{20DD}"`

But unfortunately the compiler is giving an error

```
\u escape sequence expects 4 hex digits to follow it
```

I am totally new in Swift so I don't know if I missed something here

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I have copy/pasted your exact line into a Playground, no syntax error and the expected output " i⃝". What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: @MartinR am using Xcode Version 6.0, does this has anything to do with this this issue !

Comment: The current version is Xcode 6.1 and it is working for me. I cannot tell you if it was different in Xcode 6.0 because I don't have that version anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are still using the Beta version of Xcode. 
Upgrade it to the latest one and the problem will go away.